# Data not showing from my mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm trying pull data from my MySQL server here's my php code it want show none of the data i need help

```
<?php
$action = $_GET['action'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$myID = $_GET['memberID'];

// Load Servers
$loadServers = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id = ? AND memberID = ?", array($id, $myID));                                    
if($loadServers) {
 foreach($loadServers as $loadServer) {
     $id = $loadServer['id'];
     $serverName = $loadServer['serverName'];
     $serverType = $loadServer['serverType'];
     $OS = $loadServer['OS'];
     $hostName = $loadServer['hostName'];
     $serverNode = $loadServer['serverNode'];
     $IP = $loadServer['IP'];
  }
}   
?>
```

i don't know what i'm doing wrong can somebody help me.

Comment: If you checked for php / mysql errors, then probably you would not need to ask this question at all... Not to mention the fact that your code does not print out anything.

Comment: Hello this what i get at the top of my page Notice: Undefined index: action in /var/www/panel/listserver.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: memberID in /var/www/panel/listserver.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined variable: hostName in /var/www/panel/listserver.php on line 24

Comment: Then you do not have an action parameter sent to the server in get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when i was grabbing the data from the MySQL server i had add on to the link i had set this how my link look like

Link Before

```
listserver.php?serverID=<?php echo $serverID;?>
```

Link Now

```
listserver.php?serverID=<?php echo $serverID;?>&memberID=<?php echo $memberID;?>
```

thank guys for the help i had to really look at my code in fix it